# Use one View for Multiple Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models that only differ by what fields are required, and I would like to be able to use the same view to display both of them.

I have a UserEdit class

```
public abstract class UserEdit
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [EqualTo("NewPassword")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

}
```

and a UserCreate Class that adds the required attribute to the NewPassword and ConfirmPassword properties.

```
class UserCreate_Metadata
{
    [Required]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(UserCreate_Metadata))]
public partial class UserCreate : UserEdit
{

}
```

Both of these work fine in the view if I bind the model to the specific class like so:

```
@model Siaa.NextWeb.Data.UserEdit
```

or

```
@model Siaa.NextWeb.Data.UserCreate
```

Is there a way to make the view detect which class it is binding to so that it picks up the extra validation requirement of the UserCreate class?  I tried using a dynamic view, but receive a "expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation" which research has pointed me to the lambda expressions used to create the editors

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.FirstName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most intuitive way to do this would be to combine both models onto a single model that you always pass to the view.  Then simply add some sort of flag on to the model that determines which one you should use.

```
public class UserViewModel {
    public UserCreate CreateModel { get; set; }
    public UserEdit EditModel { get; set; }

    public bool IsCreatingUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@if (Model.IsCreatingUser) {
    //Build your form.
} else {
    //Build your form.
}
```

Comment: Excuse my formatting, I'm working on it...    If I do this, don't I just have the full view in each branch of that if?

@if (Model.IsCreatingUser) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserCreate.NewPassword)
} else {
>     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEdit.NewPassword)
> }

etc, etc for each field?

Comment: Yes, more or less.  You should have an overall site layout file that contains the look and feel of your site.  Then for this particular page you should just build out the form view depending on what model you need to work with.    I'm not sure what your experience level with ASP.NET MVC is, but, it wasn't designed to pass dynamic objects to the view.  Personally I would have two different views for each scenario; the amount of extra work is not that much.

Comment: Fairly new to MVC, it does seem like it's really pushing me to duplicate the view, it just goes against my natural inclination so I was hoping for another option.